# Object; Block. Function; Hover it makes a slidedown. Hover out the slidedown, doesn't hide it. (pre-structured script)

Tags: javascript, hover

I'm rushing on something for the moment.

The object is a shopping cartblock, which, when hovered, shows the content of the cart by a slidedown object.

When you hover out the cartblock, it slides up, that's good. But when I hover out the slidedown object, nothing is happening, which is pretty frustrating for a customer.

I tried many variations of the code below but seems I can't point it.

PS: I'm new to JavaScript, clear and complete explanation will be GREATLY appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // expand/collapse management
    $('#block_cart_collapse').click(function(){
        ajaxCart.collapse();
    });
    $('#block_cart_expand').click(function(){
        ajaxCart.expand();
    });
    ajaxCart.overrideButtonsInThePage();
    ajaxCart.refresh();


    /* roll over cart */
    var cart_block = new HoverWatcher('#cart_block');
    var shopping_cart = new HoverWatcher('#shopping_cart');

    $("#shopping_cart a:first").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('border-radius', '3px 3px 0px 0px');
            if (ajaxCart.nb_total_products > 0)
                $("#cart_block").stop(true, true).slideDown(800);
        },
        function() {
            $('#shopping_cart a').css('border-radius', '3px');
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!shopping_cart.isHoveringOver() && !cart_block.isHoveringOver())
                    $("#cart_block").stop(true, true).slideUp(800);
            }, 200);
        }
    );

    $("#cart_block").hover(
        function() {
            $('#shopping_cart a').css('border-radius', '3px 3px 0px 0px');
        },
        function() {
            $('#shopping_cart a').css('border-radius', '3px');
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!shopping_cart.isHoveringOver())
                    $("#header #cart_block").stop(true, true).slideUp(450);
            }, 200);
        }
    );


    $('.delete_voucher').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({url:$(this).attr('href')});
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        if ($('body').attr('id') == 'order' || $('body').attr('id') == 'order-opc')
        {
            if (typeof(updateAddressSelection) != 'undefined')
                updateAddressSelection();
            else
                location.reload();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the trick @Askanison4,
I added the proposed line and sadly, isHoveringOver IS the issue; the pop-up appears.

But, instead of hoverout, I found a good workaround which is the following;

```
$(document).click(function() {
     $('#cart_block').fadeOut(300);
});
```

So, at least, customers can click out to close the slidedown object, pretty less annoying.

I will keep this post opened as if someone finds a solution to the hover out issue, but I'm quite satisfied for the moment.

Thanks again !!!

Comment: You can use onmouseover() and onmouseout() to work with hover and hover out events - search for those functions

Comment: Yeah ! Totally forgot this post :) As you mentionned, onmouseover() and onmouseout() WAS the greatest solution. Many thanks @Janaka !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second function declaration in your `.hover` handler. Like this:

```
$("#shopping_cart a:first").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('border-radius', '3px 3px 0px 0px');
        if (ajaxCart.nb_total_products > 0)
            $("#cart_block").stop(true, true).slideDown(800);

        // LINE REMOVED //

        $('#shopping_cart a').css('border-radius', '3px');
        setTimeout(function() {

            // THIS LINE WILL DISPLAY A POPUP IF THE TIMEOUT IS CALLED //
            alert("IF YOU SEE THIS, .isHoveringOver() is the problem");  

            if (!shopping_cart.isHoveringOver() && !cart_block.isHoveringOver())
                $("#cart_block").stop(true, true).slideUp(800);
        }, 200);
    }
);
```

Comment: Amazing try ! I was so excited about your answer as I didn't tried it but sadly, it does not work :(
I also tried adding a function to the slidedown object specifically which makes it slide up on hoverout, but did not work tho ..

Many thanks for your feedback @Askanison4

Comment: I would recommend putting an alert or something in the `setTimeout()` function to make sure that your `isHoveringOver()` if statement is not causing the trouble. If that if is not satisfied, you'd never see the menu disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How would you write this? (yeah, newbie.. lol)

Comment: Or, is there a way to add something like a modal:false; so when you click away, the slidedown object closes?
Thanks for your help.